# Problema con conversión a array u objeto

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente string, que recibo en el controlador desde un input que tiene este valor:

```
{"alumnocxc_id":32,"alumno_id":5,"producto_id":14,"name_student":"LUIS 
","cod_product":"PLN_1","product_description":"Plan para 
 TICs","price_product":500,"ciclo":"SETBRE-DICBRE 2019","product_pay":500}
{"alumnocxc_id":34,"alumno_id":5,"producto_id":15,"name_student":"LUIS","cod_product":"PLN_2","product_description":"ENE-DICIEM 
 2019","price_product":500,"ciclo":"SETBRE-DICBRE 2019","product_pay":500}
```

esos datos requiero insertarlo en base de datos, pero no he podido convertirlo, he intentado hacerlo con

> json_encode(), json_decode(), explode()

y simplemente no he podido convertirlo a un array correctamente. 
Hay otra forma de hacerlo? agradezco sus opiniones y ayuda.

Comment: ¿Vas a insertar todos esos valores en una sola celda o necesitas obtener cada valor por separado y guardarlos en celdas distintas?

Comment: No tienes que hacer nada. El controller ya debiera recibir eso como un array. Qué pasa si pones `dump(Request()->all())` (Es un POST o PUT, imagino)

Comment: @Aprendiz no, en celdas separadas necesito insertar esa informacación, pero como lo recibo como string no se como.

Comment: efectivamente es un POST @ffflabs, cuando ejecuto lo que mencionas obtnengo un array, pero solo 2, el token y el valor del input que tiene esa información. ```array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "Iqnya2xqRIejNNuxuNNaInmTbZEq1sGFfhezqbBl"
  "array_products" => "{"alumnocxc_id":32,"alumno_id":5,"producto_id":14,"name_student":" LUIS","cod_product":"PLN_1","product_description":"Plan para TICs","price_prod ▶"
] ```

Comment: oh, el input contiene un JSON "stringificado"?

Comment: así es, no se si es correcto de esta manera. tienes alguna otra idea de como pdria implementarlo

Answer (score 0):

Es necesario formatear el json desde el front para que puedas utilizar `json_decode()`
Primer punto a tomar en cuenta es que estas enviando un objeto no un array.

Desde front debes enviarlos de la siguiente manera: `JSON.stringify(array);`

En Laravel:

```
$jsonData = json_decode($request->data, true);
```

Una ves que tengas el json puedes hacer lo que gustes, si quieres insertalo, y si los nombres de los keys del objeto corresponden al nombre de las columnas, no deberias tener problema en utilizar el metodo `fill()` quedaria de la siguiente manera;

```
$tabla = new ModeloTabla();
$tabla->fill($jsonData);
```

si quieres un aray el lugar de un objeto, es facil:

```
$jsonData = (array)  json_decode($request->data, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes convertirlo por 3 razones

1. El `json` esta mal hecho, los objetos se separan por comas, {},{}
2. Al se un lista deberia usar corchetes [{},{}]
3. De hecho la es una lista de objetos ya que los `numeros` no llevan comillas

al guardar el dato en `input` seria `$("#input").val(JSON.stringify([{},{}]))`

recives `$lista = json_decode($data,true)`

acceder `$alumno_id = $lista[0]["alumno_id"]`

puedes validar tu `JSON`
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
[
   {
      "alumnocxc_id":32,
      "alumno_id":5,
      "producto_id":14,
      "name_student":"LUIS",
      "cod_product":"PLN_1",
      "product_description":"Plan para TICs",
      "price_product":500,
      "ciclo":"SETBRE-DICBRE 2019",
      "product_pay":500
   },
   {
      "alumnocxc_id":34,
      "alumno_id":5,
      "producto_id":15,
      "name_student":"LUIS",
      "cod_product":"PLN_2",
      "product_description":"ENE-DICIEM 2019",
      "price_product":500,
      "ciclo":"SETBRE-DICBRE 2019",
      "product_pay":500
   }
]
```